# Is the multiplication of convex function by a linear function convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

I have a set of convex functions $f_{ij}:\mathbb{R}_+^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

If I defined the following functions $g_{ij}:\mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}\times\mathbb{R}_+^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ by

$$
g_{ij}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=x_{ij}f_{ij}(\mathbf{y}),
$$

can this function be convex?

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}_+$, $y=(x-1)^2$ is convex, $y=(x-1)$ is convex, whereas $y=(x-1)^3$ is not...

Comment: Did you read the main of the question?

Comment: @user251257 the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n_+$

Comment: @det You are right, I was abused by your very general title.

Comment: Is $n\times n$ really intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(y)=y$ on $\mathbb R_+$, which is obviously convex and
$$ g(x,y) = xf(y) = xy $$
on $\mathbb R^2_+$. 
Then, $g$ is not convex, as its hessian is not positive semidefinite.

Or a direct proof:
$$ g(1\pm x, 1\mp x) = 1 - x^2 < 1 = g(1,1). $$

Comment: The Hessian is it $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? If so, then $\left(x, y\right)\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=2xy$. $g$ is convex iff $x^\top H x \geq 0$.

Comment: @det yes. And the rhs is not non-negative in general.

Comment: But $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_+^2$.

Comment: @det no. Please check the definition of positive semidefinite again.

Comment: Ah ok, I mix the variable of the function and the vector in the definition of positive semidefinite. Thanks.

Comment: Does it change anything if the domain was $[0, 1]^{n\times n}\times [0,1]^n$ ?

Comment: @det affine scaling won't affect convexity.